# Botframework, Luis and Json FormFlow

Tags: c#, json, botframework, formflow

I was wondering if anyone had any pointers on passing Luis entity recommendations to a dynamically created Json FormFlow?

My bot creates and calls different dialogs based on a Luis intent, and passes the entities through to the dialog. I can pass Luis entities to a standard FormFlow no problem. I use a standard function to create the Form dialog and pass the entities like so:

```
        internal static IFormDialog<T> MakeForm<T>(BuildFormDelegate<T> buildForm, List<EntityRecommendation> entitys) where T : class, new()
    {
        return new FormDialog<T>(new T(), buildForm, options: FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities: entitys);
    }
```

I've tried a similar approach with a Json Form but without success. I can call a Json form (without entities) no problem.

Any pointers would be gratefully received,